# Parâmetro $_FILES indefinido

Tags: php

Bom dia, estou tendo um problema há algum tempo em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo, todo o CRUD está funcionando perfeitamente, porém quando coloquei um campo File para adicionar foto ao cadastro, por algum motivo acaba mostrando alerta na persistência que a variável foi indefinida, quando ela deveria estar.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-persistencia" id="form-usuario" action="dao/persistencia.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <? if ($modo == 'edicao') {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $id; ?>">';
    }?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nível:(*)</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="nivel" value="admin" id="admin" <? if($modo == 'edicao') { if ($nivel == 'admin') {echo 'checked';} ;} ?>>admin</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="nivel" value="usuario" id="usuario" <? if($modo == 'edicao') { if ($nivel == 'usuario') {echo 'checked';} ;} ?>>usuario</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nome:(*)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" autofocus value="<? if($modo == 'edicao') {echo $nome;} ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Login:(*)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" id="login" value="<? if($modo == 'edicao') {echo $login;} ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Senha:(*)</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="senha" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">E-Mail:(*)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="<? if($modo == 'edicao') {echo $email;} ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Foto:</label>
        <input type="file"  name="foto" id="foto" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
                <a href="Javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" onclick="$('#conteudo-formulario').remove();">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> Fechar </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-right">
                <button disabled type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" onclick="verificaFormulario()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> Salvar </span>
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submeter"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? if($modo == 'edicao') {echo $id;} ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="modo" value="<? if($modo == 'edicao') {echo 'edicao';} else if($modo == 'insercao') {echo 'insercao';} ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="tabela" value="usuario">
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
function submeter() {
    $("#form-usuario").ajaxSubmit().data('jqxhr').done(function(data,status,xhr){
      $('#submeter').html(data);
   }).fail(function(err,status,xhr){
      console.log(err);
   });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dao/persistencia.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form-usuario').serialize(),
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        cache: false,
        // contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#submeter').html(data);
            $tabela.bootstrapTable('refresh');
            alert("Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!");
            $formulario[0].reset();
        }
    }); 
};
```

PHP

```
if ($_POST['modo'] == 'insercao') {
       $img = $_FILES;
       var_dump($img);
      // pegar o nome do arquivo, name é um atributo de vetor que está salvo
      $imgName = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
      $imgTmpName = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
      $imgSize = $_FILES['foto']['size'];
      $imgError = $_FILES['foto']['error'];
      $imgType = $_FILES['foto']['type'];

      $imgExt = explode('.', $imgName);
      $imgActualExt = strtolower(end($imgExt));

      // informação das extensões permitidas de arquivo
      $permitido = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

      // se o tipo da imagem está dentro do permitido 
      if (in_array($imgActualExt, $permitido)) {
        // verificar se não tem erros na imagem
        if ($imgError === 0) {
          // se o tamanho do arquivo for menor que 50mb
          if ($imgSize < 50000) {
            $imgNameNew = str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($_POST['nome'])).".".$imgActualExt;
            $imgDestination = '../imagens/imagens_usuario/' . $imgNameNew;
            // Move o arquivo enviado dos arquivos temporarios para o destinatario abaixo
            move_uploaded_file($imgTmpName, $imgDestination);
          } else {
            echo "Tamanho da imagem é maior do que o permitido";
          }
        } else {
          echo "Ocorreu um erro ao fazer upload da imagem!";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Extensão não permitida!";
      }

      $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO usuario (user_nivel, user_nome, user_login, user_senha, user_email, user_foto) 
                                        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['nivel'], "text"),
                                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['nome'], "text"),
                                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['login'], "text"),
                                    GetSQLValueString(md5($_POST['senha']), "text"),
                                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                                    GetSQLValueString($imgNameNew, "text"));
```

O erro da diretamente na linha em que você declara o $img como o arquivo de "foto".

Comment: Me parece tudo em ordem. Mas tive uma dúvida. Voce nao tem botao submit. Como está enviando as informções?

Comment: Você está enviando o formulário por ajax?

Comment: Sim, o botão não tem submit porque a submissão do formulário está sendo feita por AJAX.

Comment: Tem [várias perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20ajax%20upload) sobre isso no site caso ainda fique com dúvidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aleque_b, o envio de FILE por ajax não funciona igual o envio de um formulário comum.

Antes do fechamento do body e após o include do jquery, inclua o script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-FzT3vTVGXqf7wRfy8k4BiyzvbNfeYjK+frTVqZeNDFl8woCbF0CYG6g2fMEFFo/i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#form-usuario").ajaxSubmit().data('jqxhr').done(function(data,status,xhr){
          $('#submeter').html(data);
       }).fail(function(err,status,xhr){
          console.log(err);
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Verifique a biblioteca jqueryForm:

https://github.com/jquery-form/form

Comment: Colei este script em uma função Ready mas mesmo assim a persistência não reconhece o campo img.

Comment: você colocou o parâmetro **action** no formulário? <form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-persistencia" id="form-usuario" action="dao/persistencia.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Por que colocar quando você faz o envio do formulário via AJAX?

Comment: @aleque_b é como funciona a biblioteca. Você também pode passar a URL destino como parâmetro na função ajaxSubmit(), além de outras opções. Mais info -> http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

Comment: Ok, com o action setado para minha persistencia eu consegui enviar o cadastro com sucesso, porém são inseridos duas colunas no banco de dados, uma com a imagem e outra não. Acredito que esteja mandando 1 como submissão do formulário com HTML puro e outro por AJAX.

Comment: atualize o seu código na pergunta, por favor

Comment: Atualizado o código @gabriel-carvalho

Comment: @aleque_b você está enviando o ajaxSubmit() e depois o $.ajax novamente, remova o segundo por favor!

Comment: Funcionou! Me poupou muito do meu tempo do trabalho, muito obrigado!

Comment: @aleque_b por favor sinalize a resposta como correta.